# Continuous deployment Travis → Heroku

Tags: heroku, meteor, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I'm using Travis to test [CoinsManager](https://github.com/CoinsManager/CoinsManager/) everytime a commit is pushed to upstream.

And up to now, I'm regularly deploying on Heroku with the following steps:

1. update the app settings on heroku
2. generate css and commit it
3. push only the code within the app/ directory to heroku
4. remove local css commit

Which translates to:

```
$ heroku --app coinsmanager-beta config:add METEOR_SETTINGS="`cat app/settings.json`"
$ cd app/client/compass && compass compile && cd -
$ for file in `find . -name "*css"`; do git add -f $file; done; git ci -am "heroku style"
$ git push heroku-beta `git subtree split --prefix app develop`:master --force
$ git reset --soft HEAD~1 && git reset HEAD .
```

I want now to add Continuous Deployment, and get my beta version updated every time a commit is pushed on the upstream develop branch, after tests have passed.

Please read my `.travis.yml` file [here](https://github.com/CoinsManager/CoinsManager/blob/develop/.travis.yml).

I first tried to do the steps on **deploy.run**, but as you can see [in this build](https://travis-ci.org/CoinsManager/CoinsManager/builds/19704600), all the tools like wget, compass, meteor etc are not found.

When I try to move those steps in **after_success**, for example [in this build](https://travis-ci.org/CoinsManager/CoinsManager/builds/19706456), I get issues with heroku credentials required, not sure how to give them from travis while keeping that information secure.
Moreover, **after_success** is run after all builds, [regardless of the branch](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2001#issuecomment-36208993), which means that if a commit is pushed to master, and tests pass, a new build will be started on heroku using the master branch app/ data.

Any idea how to solve those issues and get my Continuous Deployment set up properly?

Comment: Did you see http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/heroku/

Answer (score 1):

I use Travis-CI and Heroku in a manner similar to what you describe, except for a yeoman based  project. If you store your Heroku API Key in a travis environment variable as HEROKU_API_KEY='Your Key' you should not have the auth issues.

I wrote a blog around this topic: http://www.parsed.io/yeoman-travis-ci-heroku/

Note that I have since moved the logic out of the yml file, but the point is still the same.